# How to initialize my singleton object

Tags: java, singleton

```
public class FooClient {

    private Foo foo;
    private final static String key = "<api-key>";

    private static FooClient client = new FooClient();

    private FooClient() {
        foo = new Foo(key);
    }

    public static FooClient getFooClient() {
        return client;
    }
}
```

1. Is it ok to initialize `client` in the above fashion.
2. Should I declare private Foo foo; as static, I am guessing its not the case.
3. If I have to support different singletons for different keys, should I modify `getFooClient(String key)` to take in a key and cache it, so that I can return singleton FooClients which are key specific.

Comment: Please stop using singletons. It makes horrible classes to test. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons You don't really need them.

Comment: If you can, stay away from singletons. They will most likely cause problems in the long run. ´new FooClient(key)´ is IMHO the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. In the constructor you can check if `client != null` and if it is - throw an error. (this will counter reflection instantiations)
2. No, it is an instance field of the singleton
3. Yes. And you should have a `Map<String, Foo>`. But note that that is not "different singletons" - your singleton is the "client". The other classes can be instantiated multiple times.

Comment: [1] is not clear, can you provide the code snippet of how it needs to look and why you think of it as problematic.

Comment: if `(client != null) throw new Error("attempted second instantiation)`. It can be problematic because one can instantiate objects even if their constructor is private - through reflection

Answer (score 2):

Usually you declare

```
private static final FooClient client = new FooClient();
```

This is the [traditional Singleton implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Traditional_simple_way). See [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for other implementation options.

I would not declare `Foo foo` as `static`.

If your singleton can return different instances based on the key, then it's a good idea to pass the key value in the `getFooClient()` method.

Comment: +1 That singleton works 95% of the times. For the rest 5% you need double-check locking with volatile.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one of something, its not a singleton.

I would use `enum` in both cases.

For the case where this is just one.

```
enum FooClient {
    INSTANCE;

    private final Foo foo = new Foo("<api-key>");
}
```

for the case where there is more than one.

```
enum FooClient {
    INSTANCE1("<api-key>"), INSTANCE2("<api-key2>");

    private final Foo foo;
    FooClient(String apiKey) {
        foo = new Foo(apiKey);
    }
}
```